# Python - = and .extend difference within for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x, extend

See example, why is there this difference between = and .extend:

```
d1=[1,2,3]
d2=[7,8,9]
d={1:d1,2:d2}

for key,value in d.items():
    value=['a','b','c']
```

output:`{1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [7, 8, 9]}`

```
for key,value in d.items():
    value.extend(['a','b','c'])
```

output:`{1: [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c'], 2: [7, 8, 9, 'a', 'b', 'c']}`

.extend appears to have a write functionality that = doesn't.  I would like to delve into why that is please.

Comment: [Extend appends to the list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html), assignment replaces the list. Note you're actually assigning something new to value, not to the dictionary list.

Comment: If you want to replace the list in-place, i.e. replace the entire content of the list without creating a new list object, you can use `value[:] = ['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first example *rebinds* `value` to a new list object. Because `value` is no longer associated with the dictionary value, the dictionary value is entirely unaffected.

The second example explicitly calls a method on the list object that alters the object in-place.

Python names are merely references to actual objects, as are dictionaries, lists, attributes, etc. If you point a name to something else (bind them to another object), all that happens to the previous object that was bound is that the reference count is decremented by 1. This can lead to the object being cleared from memory, but it won't *change the value* of the object.

But call a method on an object (such as `value.extend()`) then that method *could* affect the object. Since `list` objects are mutable, you'll see that change reflected everywhere that object is referenced.

Comment: say I want to add in the result of an equation into a list through this method would it be sensible to .pop() the figure that's already in the list, do the equation, then .extend that result into the list?  Or is there a better way?

Comment: @Robert: just assign to the index? `value[0] = function(value[0])` for example.